# I'm currently working on a text editor and need some help making a "undo change" function

Tags: java

As stated above, I'm currently working on a text-editor, just as a fun side project.

I want to include some revert/redo changes function now, but I can't quite figure out how to do so.

My current thoughts about it:

1. I need a List of bufferedReaders.
2. On document load, I create a bufferedReader anyways to paste the docs text into my textarea. This state will be the first item in my
   list
3. When the user edits the document, everytime a key press is detected, I will start a timer in a thread. If the timer runs out
   without any additional keys coming in ( lets say its on a 300ms
   timeout), it will generate a new bufferedreader and paste it into
   the list.
4. When the user demands to revert the changes, I will pick the most
   recent list entry, and overwrite the textArea with it. (This is
   where I think I will get problems, considering that the files
   *could* be huge, and this would take some time). If he wants to revert again, I will just step back one index in my list. If he
   wants to redo, step one forward.

However, I'm not quite aware if this is the best way to go, considering that a huge amount of data can come together easily. However, I can't quite figure out another idea right now how to realize this.

Are there any tips you can give me to get a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think it's more normal for undo to revert all changes since the last change in the insertion point - that is, only create a new buffer when the user clicks elsewhere or uses the arrow keys.  If you go with Typo's Command Pattern suggestion (recommended), you can add logic to your "insert text" command class to concatenate adjacent commands (that is, insertions without intervening "move insertion point" commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read about design patterns specifically the command pattern. Here's some info:

The Command pattern is known as a behavioural pattern, as it's used to manage algorithms, relationships and responsibilities between objects. The definition of Command provided in the original Gang of Four book on Design Patterns states:

**Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations**

So what does this mean in a class diagram?

[image: Command pattern]

Command declares an interface for all commands, providing a simple execute() method which asks the Receiver of the command to carry out an operation. The Receiver has the knowledge of what to do to carry out the request.  The Invoker holds a command and can get the Command to execute a request by calling the execute method. The Client creates ConcreteCommands and sets a Receiver for the command. The ConcreteCommand defines a binding between the action and the receiver. When the Invoker calls execute the ConcreteCommand will run one or more actions on the Receiver.

The following sequence diagram shows the relationship in a clearer way: 
[image: Sequence diagram]

When Would I Use This Pattern?
The Command Pattern is useful when:

- A history of requests is needed
- You need callback functionality
- Requests need to be handled at variant times or in variant orders
- The invoker should be decoupled from the object handling the
  invocation.

You'll see command being used a lot when you need to have **multiple undo operations, where a stack of the recently executed commands are maintained.** To implement the undo, all you need to do is get the last Command in the stack and execute it's undo() method.

You'll also find Command useful for wizards, progress bars, GUI buttons and menu actions, and other transactional behaviour.

**So How Does It Work In Java?**
Let's use a remote control as the example. Our remote is the center of home automation and can control everything. We'll just use a light as an example, that we can switch on or off, but we could add many more commands.

First we'll create our command interface:

```
//Command
public interface Command
{
    public void execute();
}
```

Now let's create two concrete commands. One will turn on the lights, another turns off lights:

```
//Concrete Command
public class LightOnCommand implementsCommand
{
//reference to the light
Light light;

public LightOnCommand(Light light)
{
    this.light = light;
}

public void execute()
{
    light.switchOn();
}

}


 //Concrete Command
public class LightOffCommand implementsCommand
{
//reference to the light
Light light;

public LightOffCommand(Light light)
{
    this.light = light;
}

public void execute()
{
    light.switchOff();
}

}
```

Light is our receiver class, so let's set that up now:

```
    //Receiver
   public class Light
   {
   private boolean on;

   public void switchOn()
   {
      on = true;
   }

   public void switchOff()
   {
      on = false;
   }

   }
```

Our invoker in this case is the remote control.

```
//Invoker
public class RemoteControl
{
private Command command;

public void setCommand(Command command)
{
    this.command = command;
}


public void pressButton()
{
    command.execute();
}

}
```

Finally we'll set up a client to use the invoker

```
//Client
public class Client
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RemoteControl control = new RemoteControl();

    Light light = new Light();

    Command lightsOn = new LightsOnCommand(light);
    Command lightsOff = new LightsOffCommand(light);

    //switch on
    control.setCommand(lightsOn);
    control.pressButton();

    //switch off
    control.setCommand(lightsOff);
    control.pressButton();

}

}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `public void undo();` to the command interface.

Comment: @user2760830 as tempting as that might be, it would break the pattern, in any case you should create a concrete class Undo that implements the interface

Comment: I think that would add some structure indeed. How would you go with storing the states which the textArea can be reverted to? Where would that land?

Comment: @Sossenbinder in the concrete class of the Command, not in the interface.